# Add animator to instantiated prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm new to unity so bear with me...
Created a model in Blender, complete with a metarig and animations.

Made a simple animator with an idle animation:

[image: Animator]

We have a spawner for the player (DinoSpawnLocation) with a script (DinoSpawner) to spawn the player (DinoPlayer), and the animator is added as a component:

[image: Inspector]

Here is the DinoSpawner script which should instantiate a prefab, and add the animator as a component:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DinoSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject DinoSpawn;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        Quaternion YPosition = Quaternion.Euler(0, -60, 0);
        transform.rotation = YPosition;
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(DinoSpawn, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Animator animator = DinoSpawn.GetComponent<Animator>();
        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load("Assets/Animations/Dino Controller 1.controller") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
    }


}
```

And here lies the **problem**, a clone is produced, and the animator component is added, but it doesn't link the animator controller (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

I double checked the path in the Resource.Load() method, but for some reason it won't automatically add it, and I am not receiving any errors in the console.

I feel like it should be an easy fix but have been stuck on this problem for way too long, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you did nothing to the clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sounds like `animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load("Assets/Animations/Dino Controller 1.controller") as RuntimeAnimatorController;` returns `null`.

Which makes sense because [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) is supposed to be used on assets placed in a folder called `Resources` and then also would expect s path **relative** to this `Resources` folder .. so I pretty much doubt you have placed your asset in a folder like e.g.

```
Assets/Resources/Assets/Animations/...
```

---

Anyway in general [**Don't use Resources!**](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

Simply assigning the controller asset correctly in your prefab and remove the lines after `Instantiate`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me get the problem solved. Realized my colleague didn't create a prefab for the object at the start so we couldn't assign the controller asset before instantiating the clone. Many thanks, we were stuck on that problem for a whole day.